# column not found sqlite error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

**COLUMN NOT FOUND: _PDESC WHILE COMPILING SELECT _ID, _PNAME, -PDESC ... FROM ADVTABLE**

I SAW MANY STACK OVERFLOW PAGES BEFORE ASKING THIS QUESTION BUT NOTHING HELPED.
the database gets created but whenever I try to use getdata(), it gives me the error.

and if anyone can also tell me how to search the table using _id ang get only 2 values, name and phone

```
public class advDB {
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_PNAME = "_pname";
    public static final String KEY_PDESC = "_pdesc";
    public static final String KEY_PPRICE = "_pprice";
    public static final String KEY_PLOC = "_ploc";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "_name";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "_phone";

    private final String DATABASE_NAME = "advDB";
    private final String DATABASE_TABLE = "advTable";
    private final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DBHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    public advDB(Context context)
    {
        ourContext = context;
    }

    private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        public DBHelper (Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            String sqlCode = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_PNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_PDESC + "TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_PLOC + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_PPRICE + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + KEY_NAME + "TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_PHONE + "INTEGER NOT NULL" + ")" ;

            db.execSQL(sqlCode);
        }
    }

    public long createEntry(String pname, String pdesc, String ploc, String pprice, String name, String phone)
    {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("KEY_PNAME", pname);
        cv.put("KEY_PDESC", pdesc);
        cv.put("KEY_PLOC", ploc);
        cv.put("KEY_PPRICE", pprice);
        cv.put("KEY_NAME", name);
        cv.put("KEY_PHONE", phone);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null, cv);
    }

    public String getData()
    {
        String [] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_PNAME, KEY_PDESC, KEY_PLOC, KEY_PPRICE};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns,null,null,null,null, null);
        String result = "";
        int iRowID = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iPName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PNAME);
        int iPDesc = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PDESC);
        int iPLoc = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PLOC);
        int iPPrice = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PPRICE);

        for (c.moveToFirst();c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
        {
            result = result + c.getString(iRowID) + ": " + c.getString(iPName) + " " + c.getString(iPDesc) + " " + c.getString(iPLoc) + " " + c.getString(iPPrice) + "/n";
        }
        c.close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Describe what you are trying to do. Then show the output or behavior of what happens. Show what you have tried. Ask a specific question.

Comment: Is this an exact copy of the error message  "COLUMN NOT FOUND: _PDESC WHILE COMPILING SELECT _ID, _PNAME, -PDESC ... FROM ADVTABLE" or did you make a typo with  ", -PDESC"?

Comment: @Barns52 I initially thought that, but can't find `-PDESC` anywhere in the example code. Plenty of other issues to be found though.

Comment: sorry, its _PDESC. can you tell me the other error too.

Comment: ourDatabase.getReadableDatabase()? didnt understand this

Comment: @rishabh :: before you can actually query the database you must get an open database object with something like ourDatabase= this.getReadableDatabase();

Comment: ` public advDB open() throws SQLException
    {
        ourHelper = new DBHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    } `

i have this. i removed it from above because the site was not letting me put the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo. In your `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
+ KEY_PDESC + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
```

You're missing a space before `TEXT NOT NULL,`. Correct this to:

```
+ KEY_PDESC + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
```

Same with `KEY_NAME` and `KEY_PHONE`.

One other thing, remove the quotes from the keys for your `ContentValues` object, as you're using constants. i.e:

```
cv.put(KEY_PNAME, pname);
```

Comment: I corrected that. but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you uninstalled your app and re-installed? The table needs to be dropped and recreated before this change can take effect.

Comment: ** Now, i am not getting the same error. But the app closes when i use getdata() **

`try
        {
            advDB db = new advDB(this);
            db.open();
            tvView.setText(db.getData());
            db.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }`

it shows error at the tvView line.

Comment: and 
and at the result line
           ` result = result + c.getString(iRowID) + ": " + c.getString(iPName) + " " + c.getString(iPDesc) + " " + c.getString(iPLoc) + " " + c.getString(iPPrice) + "\n";`